# Filter cms collection by store id before the store is saved

Tags: module, collection

I have a custom module where an item (slider) has to be linked with a cms page. The website is multistore.

So when the user inserts an item in my module I show a collection of cms pages where he can choose the page to link to.

The issue is with a new item where he didn't yet save the store view so I don't have yet the store id in the database.

How do you get around it? Filter by store view but don't get the store view from the database, but from what the user has clicked in the previous field?

I know about php being ended on server side, but is there some magento magic that can be done or should the user always have to save the storeview first? Or another approach?

```
$cms_collection = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
    ->addStoreFilter($model->getData('store_id'));      
$options = array();
foreach($cms_collection as $cms_page){
    $options[$cms_page->getId()] = $cms_page->getIdentifier();
}

$fieldset->addField('cms_id', 'select', array(
    'name'      => 'cms_id',
    'label'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Cms page'),
    'title'     => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Cms page'),
    'required'  => false,
    'options'   => $options,
));
```

Comment: Is this a frontend feature or a backend feature?

Comment: @RiccardoT backend

Comment: IMHO  the only option is to let the user choose the store